# How do I convert milliseconds into DateTime in Power Bi?

Tags: timestamp, powerbi, unix-timestamp, powerbi-desktop

I have a table that has 13 digit timestamps (milliseconds I believe) but I can't convert them in Power Bi for some reason. I've looked at many methods online and it should work but I keep getting an error each time I try to convert. (This is from transform data and after adding a custom column)

[image]

When I try to convert the timestamps in "created" column into a new custom column I get an error. This is the formulae I use when creating a new column.

```
#datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) + #duration(0, 0, 0, [Created]/1000)
```

This apparently works for other people who have the same problem but not for me and I'm not sure why that is, I just keep getting Errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message might give a clue. What does it say if you click on one of those errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that your `[Created]` column is formatted as text.

Try converting that column to a numerical type before writing a custom column that tries to divide by 1000.

Comment: I thought what you said was right but I'm still getting an error, I've just checked, my created table is a whole number format, not a text format. There's still an error with it.

Comment: Okay, weird, I've got it working now. For some reason in query editor it was coming up with errors, yet when I actually just accepted changes it turned out fine, thank you anyway Alexis!